# What is UNK Token in Vector Representation of Words

Tags: tensorflow, nlp

```
# Step 2: Build the dictionary and replace rare words with UNK token.
vocabulary_size = 50000


def build_dataset(words, n_words):
  """Process raw inputs into a dataset."""
  count = [['UNK', -1]]
  count.extend(collections.Counter(words).most_common(n_words - 1))
  dictionary = dict()
  for word, _ in count:
    dictionary[word] = len(dictionary)
  data = list()
  unk_count = 0
  for word in words:
    if word in dictionary:
      index = dictionary[word]
    else:
      index = 0  # dictionary['UNK']
      unk_count += 1
    data.append(index)
  count[0][1] = unk_count
  reversed_dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary.values(), dictionary.keys()))
  return data, count, dictionary, reversed_dictionary

data, count, dictionary, reverse_dictionary = build_dataset(vocabulary,
                                                            vocabulary_size)
```

I am learning the elementary example of Vector Representation of Words using Tensorflow.

This Step 2 is titled as "Build the dictionary and replace rare words with UNK token", however, there's no prior defining process of what "UNK" refers to.

To specify the question:

0) What does UNK generally refer to in NLP?

1) What does count = [['UNK', -1]] mean? I know the bracket [] refer to list in python, however, why do we collocating it with -1?

Comment: `UNK` means unknown word, a word that doesn't exist the the vocabulary set.

Comment: It seems that `count` is supposed to be a list of pairs of form `['word', number_of_occurences]`. `-1` is apparently a placeholder value which later is filled with `count[0][1] = unk_count`. It's a bad, slow, non-"pythonic way" code. Guido would throw up if he would see this. You will find a lot of bad code in TF tutorials and in TF itself. People from Google and related community often just "make things work" and move on. They don't care whether someone will need to read the resulting mess. Don't look for wisdom there. Use external sources of information when in doubt.

Comment: It looks important criticize. Whic external lookups do you recommend?

Comment: Yes, it is also very easy to criticize =) For now try to take what you can from Tensorflow, and make things done. Just keep in mind that python examples there are quite hairy. When you'll be more comfortable with TF, you may look into "pythonic way". There are other frameworks too (e.g. [PyTorch](http://pytorch.org) is cool and trendy now, or [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/), which is a classic, or [Keras](https://keras.io/) that wraps Tensorflow into a simple interface).

Answer (score 8):

As it is already mentioned in the comments, in tokenizing and NLP when you see the `UNK` token, it is probably to indicate **unknown word**.

for example, if you want to predict a missing word in a sentence. how would you feed your data to it? you definitely need a token for showing that where is the missing word. so if the "house" is our missing word, after tokenizing it will be like:

> `'my house is big'` -> `['my', 'UNK', 'is', 'big']`

PS: that `count = [['UNK', -1]]` is for initionalizing the `count`, and it will be like `[['word', number_of_occurences]]` as  Ivan Aksamentov has already said.